# No data when exporting a plot

Tags: netlogo

I am learning NetLogo using Railsback and Grimm book. I am trying to replicate some models using NetLogo 5.1.0 on a Mac.

I created a plot to show how corridor width changes over ticks. I can see the line on the plot, but when I export the data to a .csv file, I get no information about the plot:

```
    "export-plot data (NetLogo 5.1.0)"
    "ch04_butterfly_v2.nlogo"
    "01/02/2015 14:52:55:280 -0600"

    "MODEL SETTINGS"
    "number","q"
    "50","0.48"

    """Corridor Width"""
    "x min","x max","y min","y max","autoplot?","current pen","legend open?","number of pens"
    "0","1","0","100","true","""""","false","0"

    "pen name","pen down?","mode","interval","color","x"
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the patience.

**My code:**

```
globals [ ] 
patches-own [ elevation used?]
turtles-own [ start-patch ]

to setup
ca

file-open "ElevationData.txt" 
while [not file-at-end?]
  [
    let next-x file-read 
    let next-y file-read
    let next-elevation file-read
    ask patch next-x next-y [set elevation next-elevation]
   ]
file-close  

let min-elevation min [elevation] of patches 
let max-elevation max [elevation] of patches

ask patches [    
    set pcolor scale-color green elevation min-elevation max-elevation
    set used? false
   ]

crt number [
    set size 2
    setxy 85 95
    pen-down
    set start-patch patch-here
   ]  
reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [move]
  plot corridor-width
tick
if ticks >= 1000
   [ 
    export-plot "corridor width" (word "corridor-output-for-q-" q ".csv")
    stop 
   ]

end

to move 
  if elevation >= [elevation] of max-one-of neighbors [elevation]
  [stop]
  ifelse random-float 1 < q
  [ uphill elevation ]
  [ move-to one-of neighbors]
  set used? true
end

to-report corridor-width
  let patch-visited count patches with [used?]
  let mean-distance mean [distance start-patch] of turtles 
  ifelse mean-distance > 0
  [report patch-visited / mean-distance]
  [report]
end
```

Comment: Could the second point be linked to the problem mentioned in the errata ( http://www.railsback-grimm-abm-book.com/Railsback-Grimm2012_Errata.pdf ) Section 5.4, page 68?

Comment: I don't think so. When I export the plot directly from the GUI interface that results in a .csv file, I have the same problem.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time — that's the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. There isn't any known problem with exported plot files being empty like this. Can you provide a URL of the complete .nlogo file? Curious if I can reproduce the problem on my own machine.

Comment: Here a .nlogo file: https://github.com/sdaza/netlogo-examples/tree/master/railback%20%26%20grimm's%20book/ch05